# How to group different texts into groups python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `data frame` that contains strings in it. 
I want to group the strings into 3 categories:

- The **first category** is strings that only have the words in the
  defined list and nothing else but that. The words can be in any order as long as the string only contains words from that list. Additionally, it does not have to include all the words from the list.
- The **second category** is the first category in addition to other
  words that may not be on the list.
- The **third category** is everything that is not the first two
  categories

I started by cleaning the data by removing all punctuations and converting the text to lower case.

**Example:**

```
list = ["dog name", "dog age", "dog breed"]
```

For something to be in the **first category**, it's string should look exactly like this:

```
"dog name dog age dog breed".
```

**or**

```
"dog age dog name"
```

For something to be in the **second category**, its string would look something like this:

```
  "dog name suzie dog age 4 dog breed pug"
```

**or**

```
"dog name suzie dog breed pug"
```

For something to be in the **third category**, its string would look something like this:

```
"my dogs name is suzie and she is a pug who is 4 years old"
```

Any suggestions/advice on how to group these?

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow! Please  provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are these rules hierarchical? So if the strings are identical, but also contains one or more words from your list, you'd want to categorize them in category 1?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to document *all* your requirements, like the ones you added in a comment to the now-deleted answer (which seems to solve precisely the question as it is currently articulated).

Comment: @tripleee have taken your suggestion :)

Comment: @ALollz I saw your suggestion to saw my question, using `if any`, so for the first category, the order in which the words are in the string do not matter as long as only the words in that list are in the strings, and nothing else, how do you recommend doing this without doing all the different combinations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's pseudocode for you.

Remember the original string `orig`.

Remove all the phrases on the list from the string and put the result in `new`.

If `orig` == `new` you have category 3.

Else, if `new` is empty,you have category 1.

Else, you have category 2.

Using `new= re.sub(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(list) + r')\b', orig)` replaces all the phrases, taking word boundaries intoe ccount. (Though you really don't want to call your variable `list`, because this will shadow the Python built-in type.)